# What does the word "You-ee" mean?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Someone was talking over the Telephone :

- I got a traffic ticket today doing a **you-ee** on Beverly Drive.

What does the **you-ee** represent in the  sentence above?

Comment: It's "U" for U-turn with a diminutive "ee" ("-y" "-ie") tacked on, like an "ow-ie".

Comment: "Hold on...I gotta hand a 'U-y'. I turned wrong out of the packy"

Comment: @Mitch: Is that a typo, or do you really talk about ***handing** a u-ey?* It's always ***hang** a u-ey* to me (and until now I'd always thought it was peculiarly British).

Comment: ...but I did just come across some (Aussie?) guy discussing this very usage who says [Where I come from you **hand** a u-ey.](http://languagehat.com/aussie-slang/)

Comment: @Starkeen The big question in my mind is how did you not ask the person on the other end of the telephone what they meant? Did you just fake it?

Comment: @DigitalChris - At a random guess, Starkeen was *watching a television show*, on which someone was using a telephone.

Comment: @FumbleFingers argh... a typo. for me 'hang a U-y' or rather what people in my youth would say. Nowadays, I have my driver say it.

Comment: That link doesn't mention 'hand a U-ey'. Is there some other better link? (stupidgoogle isn't giving a 'hand')

Comment: You know, I've always had a spelling in my head for this word but I don't actually know what it is so thanks for actually finding a spelling.

Comment: @Mitch: *My* driver insists it's not physically possible to *hang a u-ey* in a stretch limo! :~)

Comment: @FumbleFingers [Time to upgrade your limo driver](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eM4SHAw2Bzk).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I was under the impression that Australians "Chuck a u-ey". Source: Home and Away.

Comment: @Richard: I was gonna say we Brits have been known to [***throw** a u-ey*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22throw+a+u-ey%22) after imbibing too much of the amber nectar. But it turns out both instances of that in Google Books are from Americans, referring to the delicate driving manoeuvre.

Comment: I've never heard "hand" a uwie in Australia. I've heard "hang", "chuck" and various other forms, but never "hand" I expect @FumbleFingers correspondent simply mistyped "hang"

Comment: @DigitalChris: That's not a u-ee - no U.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

***[You-ee](http://www.yourdictionary.com/youee)*** is an alternative form of  ***[uey](http://www.yourdictionary.com/uey) or u-ey:***

Noun
(plural ueys)

> - (Australia, Canada, UK, US, colloquial, informal) ***A U-turn.***

A ***[U-turn](http://www.yourdictionary.com/u-turn)*** is a turn (usually made by a vehicle) in the shape of a 'U':

Noun
(plural U-turns)

> - (literally) A turn in a vehicle carried out by driving in a semicircle in order to travel in the opposite direction.

(yourdictionary.com)

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that one would typically 'hang' or 'pull' a U-ey. You could say 'perform' but mixing formal and informal terms sounds weird.

Answer (score 15):

[U-ie](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=U-ie&defid=1859036), pronounced U E, is short for a U-turn made while driving.